# Is there a way of increasing fps of real time camera feed in raspberry pi?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, signal-processing, frame-rate

I am using Raspberry Pi 4 and HTPA32x32d thermal camera sensor. I am using https://github.com/cjcbusatto/thermografree this fork for reading camera with I2C. My main code takes the 32x32 sensor output and transforms into a viewable image using cv2.resize() function and shows on the screen. I am getting range in between 2-4 fps. I want to increase the fps of my real-time thermal imaging. Can you suggest anything to increase my fps?

I am thinking to predict frames but i dont know a method for that or is it sufficient for real time fps increment? If not or if you have a better approach i could use the information.

Update #1

I have not tried anything yet. I am looking for method to increase fps. I have an idea to gather 3 frames and predict few frames between them to increase up to 10 fps. Since 2 frames of a video has minimum change between them. But i dont know how to begin.

Sample code is given below:

```
#IMPORT PACKAGES
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from htpa import *

size = (256,256) #frame size

#initialize IR camera module 
ir = HTPA(0x1A)

while(1):
    start_time = time.time()
    #generate termal image and temperature array
    temps, ta = ir.capture_temperatures()
    irIm = cv2.resize(temps, size, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    norm_image = np.uint8(cv2.normalize(irIm, None, alpha = 0, beta = 255, 
    norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_8UC1))
    hotIm = cv2.applyColorMap(norm_image,cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)

    cv2.imshow("Result", hotIm)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    print("fps ; ", 1.0/(time.time()-start_time))

    #if the 'q' key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
       break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Sample frame of the camera feed:

[image]

Update #2

When i read only `temps, ta = ir.capture_temperatures()` without any processing(even display) the fps is average of 4.0 moving between 3.2 to 4.2.

When read and processed (not displayed) the fps moves between 3.0 and 4.0 with average of 3.7.

Comment: Please include the actual code you are using and any output it has so that users may help. What have you tried? What has the result been? Research?

Comment: Try timing purely the capture (with absolutely no processing, or display) of, say, 100 frames. That will give you the best frame rate you could ever hope to achieve. Then try capturing 1 frame and processing the time to process it (without any display) over and over again 100 times. Then report back the results.

Comment: Updated as you wish if I did not understand falsely your question @MarkSetchell  .

Comment: `capture_temperature()` calls `capture_image()` which calls `expose_block()` four times which internally waits 5ms - this really sets an upper limit on how fast you will get. Maybe try reducing the 5ms delay on line 43 to see if it is stable at 3ms or 2ms...

Comment: It does not change anything only 0.1 fps increase is observed. It it is about hardware and I2C speed limits. But the manifacturer's program is working at 10 fps. I had the test kit before to test the sensor.

Comment: Have you checked your I2C clockrate in your boot config? And tried increasing it?

Comment: Yes. It is normally 400kHz tried to increase 1 Mhz but nothing changed much. that's why I am looking for a signal processing solution.

Comment: I think you are going to need to instrument your code to work out where the time is being used. I have had great success with `sigrok` software and a cheap $12 probe (8 channel) from Amazon. I just write different GPIO pins high and low at start and end of different Python/C functions to measure their duration.

Answer (score 1):

I looked datasheet of htpa32x32d. And I see this solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eui1E.png)
in htpa.py:

```
    def set_clock_speed(self, clk):
    if clk > 63:
        clk = 63
    if clk < 0:
        clk = 0

    clk = int(clk)
    print(clk)
    clk_speed = self.generate_command(0x06,clk)

    self.send_command(clk_speed)
```

you can change clk value so this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Link to source code](https://github.com/cjcbusatto/thermografree/blob/master/src/htpa.py)

Looking at the code, Line 252 in `htpa.py` that could be the cause for a delay.

`while not self.block_capture_finished(block, blind, vdd):`

`time.sleep(0.005)`

Try `time.sleep(0.001)` and see if there is any improvement.

Another cause could be the resize use in `capture_display.py` line 20.

Try `im = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=4, fy=4)`

Comment: Unfortunately it merely helps as It changes the results say 4.0 to 4.1 fps.